# TypeError:unsupported format string passed to Series.__format__

Tags: python, django

I am trying to print time in 12 hour clock format but django throws TypeError. works fine for python but shows error in django
Thanks is Advance

```
def solve(s, n):
    h, m = map(int, s[:-2].split(':'))
    h =h% 12
    if s[-2:] == 'pm':
        h =h+ 12
    t = h * 60 + m + n
    h, m = divmod(t, 60)
    h =h% 24
    if h < 12:
        suffix = 'a' 
    else:
        suffix='p'
    h =h% 12
    if h == 0:
        h = 12
    return "{:02d}:{:02d}{}m".format(h, m, suffix)

solve('10:00am',45)
```

returns 10:45am

Comment: Why try to implement function like this, when the strftime can do this for you:print(datetime.today().strftime("%I:%M %p"))

Comment: i wanted to add minutes to a 12 hour clock and get an output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said, use strftime to do this dirty work, instead of doing it on your own.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def solve(s, minutes):
    time_instance = datetime.strptime(s, '%I:%M%p')
    time_instance += timedelta(minutes=minutes)
    return time_instance.strftime('%I:%M%p').lower()


print(solve('10:00am', 45))  # 10:45am
print(solve('10:00pm', 45))  # 10:45pm
print(solve('11:30pm', 45))  # 12:15am
print(solve('11:30pm', 120))  # 01:30am
```

Comment: this works fine when used with python as soon as i connect it to django getting ```unsupported type for timedelta minutes component: Series```

Comment: Debug and check what's your real data type is being passed in your Django Website